# How to customize the default login page in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, authentication, activeadmin

**The Problem**

I'm trying to customize the default login page in ActiveAdmin, but I'm having trouble getting the customizations to go through.

**What I've tried**

A commenter on [this RailsCasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?view=comments) suggests copying [this file](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb) to `app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` and customizing it from there. However, doing so does not seem to replace the default login form.

I also tried replacing `devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config` with `devise_for :admin_users` as the commenter suggests, which seems to point the routes to the right place, but I get a bunch of server errors related to none of the ActiveAdmin variables being recognized in this context.

I've searched the docs, but I haven't been able to find documentation around customizing the login form in particular.

**Question**

What's the best way to go about customizing the login form in ActiveAdmin?

Comment: the path you created is just fine, also if you didn't restart your server after the change do so.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With the default ActiveAdmin config where the Devise resource is `admin_user`, your `new.html.erb` should go in `app/views/admin_users/sessions/new.html.erb` instead.

An easy way to copy out all the Devise templates is to do `rails g devise:views admin_users`, though it turns out ActiveAdmin comes with its own versions of these views: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/tree/master/app/views/active_admin/devise

If you're additionally trying to change the layout that Devise's `new.html.erb` is rendered with, you can copy the layout file out from ActiveAdmin into `app/views/layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb`

The current layout file used for the login page is here:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/views/layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb

Comment: In my case, replace `app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` is the right way

Answer (score 9):

First copy all the devise views to your app:

```
rails g devise:views admin_users
```

Second add `config.scoped_views = true` inside the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file will do the trick.

In this way you don't need to override active_admin templates.